# Form is nested too deep

Tags: angular, typescript

My form has dynamic controls. This is how I defined them:

```js
form = this._formBuilder.group({
  services: this._formBuilder.array([])
});
```

```js
const servicesFormArray = this.form.get('services') as FormArray;

for (let service of quotation.services) {
  const serviceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    [service.serviceName]: this._formBuilder.control(false)
  });
  servicesFormArray.push(serviceFormGroup);
}
```

`console.log(this.form)` gives me the following result:

[image]

My goal is to simplify the form controls and to get rid of `0: FormGroup` and the second `controls`. So I want to the structure to be like this:

```
- controls
  - services
    - controls
      - My Product
```

I also tried it this way:

```js
const servicesFormArray = this.form.get('services') as FormArray;

for (let service of quotation.services) {
  const serviceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    [service.serviceName]: this._formBuilder.control(false)
  });
  
  const serviceControl = serviceFormGroup.get(service.serviceName);
  
  servicesFormArray.push(serviceControl);
}
```

But then I get this structure:

```
- controls
  - services
    - controls
      - [0]
```

How can I achieve the desired structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `formArray`, we can just set a `formGroup` and then use `addControl` method to add the individual form values!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  form = this._formBuilder.group({
    services: this._formBuilder.group({}),
  });

  quotation = {
    services: [
      {
        serviceName: 'test',
      },
      {
        serviceName: 'test1',
      },
      {
        serviceName: 'test2',
      },
    ],
  };

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const servicesFormArray = this.form.get('services') as FormGroup;

    for (let service of this.quotation.services) {
      servicesFormArray.addControl(
        service.serviceName,
        this._formBuilder.control(false)
      );
    }
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xnwe3t?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)